# The wav file wont play after using pyinstaller --onefile.I just hear the windows 'beep'

Tags: windows, pycharm, pyinstaller

> This program displays a home circuit breaker panel. the user can view what is on each breaker on the panel (data taken from an imported dictionary of entered breaker panel info) or the user can check what breakers control any list zone (kitchen basement, etc) The breakerville program closes when the user decides and is supposed to play a wave file at the close. It doesn't play after the program is made into an exe with pyinstaller just the windows 'beep'.
> I am suspecting that I may need to edit the spec file to get the wave file to work after compiled. Is this correct and if so how?  Do I need to modify the spec file?

```
        from playsound import playsound  # CURRENTLY USING
        from chart import chart
        from BreakerZones import BreakerZones
        import time
        import sys
        import colorama
        import yaml  # to print the nested_lookup results(n) on separate lines
        from nested_lookup import nested_lookup, get_all_keys # importing 2 items from nested_lookup
        from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
    
    
    colorama.init(autoreset=True)  # If you don't want to print Style.RESET_ALL all the time,
                                   # reset automatically after each print statement with True
    print(colorama.ansi.clear_screen())
    
    print('\n'*4)  # prints a newline 4 times
    
    
    print(Fore.MAGENTA + '                             Arriving-' + Fore.GREEN + '    *** BREAKERVILLE USA ***')
    
    def main():
    
    
    print('\n' * 2)
    print(Fore.BLUE + '   Breaker Numbers and Zones')

    k = get_all_keys(BreakerZones)
    # raw amount of keys even repeats , has quotes

    new_l = []                                         # eliminate extra repeating nested keys
    for e in k:                                        # has quotes
        if e not in new_l and sorted(e) not in new_l:  #
            new_l.append(e)                            #
    print()

    new_l.sort()  # make alphabetical
    newer_l = ('%s' % ', '.join(map(str, new_l)).strip("' ,"))  # remove ['%s'] brackets so they don't show up when run
    print(' ', yaml.dump(newer_l, default_flow_style=False))    #  strip("' ,")  or will see leading "' ," in output

    print(Fore.BLUE + '   ENTER A BREAKER # OR ZONE', Fore.GREEN + ': ', end='')
    i = input().strip().lower()  # these lines is workaround for the colorama
    print()              # user input() issue of 'code' appearing in screen output

    if i in k:
        n = (nested_lookup(i, BreakerZones, wild=False, with_keys=False))   # wild=True means key not case sensitive,
        print(yaml.dump(n, default_flow_style=False))                       # 'with_keys' returns values + keys also
        # for key, value in n.items():     eliminated by using yaml
        #    print(key, '--', value)       eliminated by using yaml
    else:
        print(Fore.YELLOW + ' Typo,' + Fore.GREEN + ' try again')
        main()

    print()

    print(Fore.GREEN + '           Continue? Y or N: C for breaker chart : ', end='')  # see comments ENTER A BREAKER
    ans = input().strip().lower()      # strip() removes any spaces before or after user input

    if ans == 'c':
        chart()
        print()
        print(Fore.GREEN + '           Continue? Y or N : ', end='')
        ans = input().strip().lower()             # strip() removes any spaces before or after user input
        if ans == 'y':                            # shorter version 'continue Y or N' after printing breaker chart
            main()
        else:
            print()
            print(Fore.MAGENTA + '                            Departing -' + Fore.GREEN + '   *** BREAKERVILLE ***')

        playsound('train whistle.wav')

        time.sleep(2) # delay to exit program
        sys.exit()

    elif ans != 'y':
        print()
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + '                            Good Day -' + Fore.GREEN + '   *** BREAKERVILLE ***')

        playsound('train whistle.wav') #CURRENTLY USING

        time.sleep(2)  # delay to exit program

        sys.exit()

    else:
        main()


main()
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context please ? And put all the code in the code block

Comment: Can you confirm your code is working as a script. I made a very small similar example to use playsound and it was not working from PyCharm. I had to provide the full path to the wave to have it work perfectly. The exe then created with pyinstaller is also working great

Comment: The script works great. It's visually nice. The wave file does play when run in Pycharm. Id love to check out the example that you made providing the full path for pyinstaller.

Comment: Here it is, cannot be simpler. If I remove the full path the script is crashing.
from playsound import playsound  # CURRENTLY USING
def main():
        playsound(r'g:\__Workspace\test\Train Loop.wav') #CURRENTLY USING
main()

Comment: thank you Eric. Im working on understanding what you sent. In my case Im thinking the path would be   
 playsound(r'C:__Users\oseda\PycharmProjects\
    FirstProject\ExperiVille.py\train whistle.wav') Where do I use the path information in my program?

Comment: Just replace 'train whistle.wav' with that full path

Comment: I get it.     playsound('C:/Users/oseda/PycharmProjects/FirstProject/train_whistle.wav')

Comment: It works after pyinstaller. thanks Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the records: The issue is fixed by providing full path to the sound file.
This is probably linked to the implementation of playsound and how it determines what is the current working directory. Please refer to https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information for a better understanding of that topic with pyinstaller